# Trouble hiding menu on single page

Tags: menus, css

I'm trying to hide the two top bars on this single wordpress page: https://grassiusa.com/try/ that will eventually serve as a single lead generating landing page with no menu, but I seem to be stuck.

The page id is .page-id-17091 and I've tried inserting a number of css combinations based on previous post answers, but nothing is working. I must be missing something. Can somebody please inspect the page and help me with the css to edit this?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
.page-id-17091 div.fixed-header-box { display: none; }
```

I'd generally prefer setting the theme up to not generate the header for that page, though, rather than hiding it after the fact.